# Azure blob SAS URL 403 in browser img tag but downloads fine

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have an Azure storage account where i store blobs in containers,
I am generating SAS URL in order to show the images in my react web app,
when pasting the URL to the browser everything works fine and the image is being downloaded,
but when I try to display it as an img tag in the browser I am receiving the following issue:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
```

It started to happen a day ago and before it worked fine.
A sample form of URL that I generate is:

https://{{storageName}}.blob.core.windows.net/{{ContainerName}}/5261a483-e131-40f9-90b2-91657b1daec7.png?sv=2020-10-02&st=2022-01-01T10%3A58%3A20Z&se=2022-01-01T11%3A01%3A27Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=vN2k3%2BD04BDwnSIDx%2F%2FDyGfUt1UIIoivfOzdfh0kWG0%3D

And the code I am using to generate it is:

```
  try {
//get extesnsion of promo image
var containerName = container;
const client = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
if (!containerName)
  return '';
//get extesnsion of promo image


const blobName = imageName;
const blobClient = client.getBlobClient(blobName);

const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
  containerName,
  blobName,
      permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("r"),
      startsOn: new Date(),
      expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 186400)
    },
      cerds
    ).toString();
    // await sleep(0);
    const sasUrl = blobClient.url + "?" + blobSAS;
    // console.log(sasUrl);
    return sasUrl;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return '';
  }
```

Why is this happening? how can it be that from the browser URL I always get a good response and can download the image and from the img tag i am getting a 403?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code for SAS generation. More than likely the issue is coming because of URL encoding/decoding. Are you using the exact URL in your img tag?

Comment: Worth checking the settings of your azure storage account under Networking section and then Firewalls and Virtual networks you can verify if All networks is selected. If not then you have to ensure that the client you are using to access the url is on one of the selected networks specified: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

On work around try with solution

**Solution 1)** check  if your storage account is **firewall enabled** .

**Azure Portal -> Storage Account -> Networking -> Check Allow Access From (All Networks / Selected Networks)**

If it is "**Selected Networks**" - It means the storage account is firewall enabled.
If the storage account is firewall enabled, **check your app is whitelisted to access.**

For more details refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/334786/azure-blob-storage-fails-to-authenticate-34make-su.html

**Solution 2)** Check with  **SAS( shared access signature) that expired**. Try with updating the new one